# my http request does not work

Tags: swift

I have update my xcode and i have problem with https requests. I need to get html code. But some sites is get good, some is nil. i think problem with plist file, but presvious version in log say about Clear Http and unsecured loads. The current xcode - no. Why i have catch with some web sites? Yandex.ru - i can get html content. Google.com - i cannot(go to catch block). This problem with different sites. Part of them i can get, second part i cant. Thank you for resolve my problem.

There is my code:

```
if let url = URL(string: "http://google.com") {
  do {
    let contents = try String(contentsOf: url)
    print(contents)
  } catch {
    print("catch")
  }
} else {
  print("else")
}
```

my plist file  in attach:

[image]

Comment: You are strongly discouraged from loading data from a remote URL with synchronous API like `String(contentsOf`

Answer (score 0):

Rather than catching with a `print("catch")` you should try to print the error that's being thrown

```
catch (let e) {
    print(e)
}
```

The error I am seeing is `Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=261 "The file couldn’t be opened using text encoding Unicode (UTF-8)." UserInfo={NSURL=http://google.com, NSStringEncoding=4}`

I tried

```
let contents = try String(contentsOf: url, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
```

but that doesn't seem to solve the problem.  Depends on how Google is serving up their pages

**MOST IMPORTANTLY**

This is a blocking call - you should use an async method for loading remote URLs.  This method is really for loading local assets from your Bundle.  Please look at `NSURLRequest` https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurlrequest and `NSURLSession` https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurlsession

Comment: i think this is not problem with encoding, because i try http://staraya-samara.ru   - all ok. I try http://antennaxxi.ru  -  go catch. Why??

Comment: The same problem with different code: let url = URL(string: "http://mou16.himki-edu.ru")!
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url, completionHandler: { ( data , response , error ) in
            
            DispatchQueue.main.async{
                let serverString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
                print("server answer - \(serverString)")
            }
        })
        task.resume()
        print("task.resume()")
    }

Answer (score 0):

I find problem - all this web sites is not UTF-8. I try different and it is work:

var serverString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.windowsCP1251.rawValue)